# Debugging resource strings are unavailable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, silverlight

I am working on a Silverlight web application in Visual Studio 2010.

I recently made the mistake of updating to the latest version Silverlight when prompted through the browser. Consequently, I was unable to build (or even load) my Silverlight application.

To get around this, I installed the Silverlight 5 Developer runtime - which enabled me to build and deploy the application.

However, when I deploy to a locked down test machine, and run the web application, I get an exception something like the following:

"Debugging resource strings are unavailable..."

The test machine appears to have the 'standard' 64-bit Silverlight runtime installed, version 5.1.20513.0.

It appears that the runtime on the test machine is the 'standard' runtime, not the 'Developer' runtime. Because the test machine is locked down, I am unable to install the 'Developer' runtime - so I am forced to find a setup that will both compile on my development machine, and will run on test.

I have tried several combinations of reinstalling Silverlight, with various back versions - but nothing seems to work.

So I am in a quandary:

1. Compiling on the dev machine won't work without the 'Developer' runtime.
2. The application cannot be run on the test machine without the Developer runtime being present - which cannot be installed (and shouldn't be necessary - in principle - given that it was working before!).

Is there a 'trick' here that I am missing?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, I was missing a (required) setting in the Web.Config file.

The "Debugging Strings not available" appears when there is a fault in the application, but the relevant fault code(s) cannot be translated into something more human-readable, (due to the absence of the required DLLs or some such).

After having updated the Web.Config, the problem disappeared.

---

It turns out that it was a Key/Value pair that was missing from Web.Config:

```
<add key="DashboardDataRetrievalMethod" value="UseSummaryTable" />
```

The application was specifically looking for this, and complained with a rather generic error message with no stack trace etc.

Comment: It would be helpful to other users if you added the missing setting you added to the web.config?

Comment: @Shiv The setting in Web.config turned out to be something internal to the web application I was writing. If the application is looking for a constant in Web.config that doesn't exist, then we get an error with *no* stack trace.